# I am missing some relation between ampitude and intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation

Suppose a lamp emits monochromatic light uniformily in all directions. Let the lamp be 3% efficient in converting electrical power to EMW, and consumes 100W of power. At distance of 5m, in an area of $4\pi(5)^2=100\pi$ m$^2$, this power is distributed so that the intensity there would be $100W*0.03/(100\pi)=3/(100\pi)$ J/(m$^2$s). I know that the intensity is proportional to amplitude squared and is given by:

$$I=\frac12(\rho SV)\omega^2A^2 \tag{1}$$

but many unknown are here. How should I thus calculate the amplitude of electrical field? I suppose it would be 2-3V/m or near 2.5V/m according to my friend.

Comment: Could you edit your question and specify what are $\rho$, $S$ , etc?

Comment: @Mahdi $\rho$=density S=cross-section area , v=velocity, $\omega$=frequency , A=amplitude, sim. to [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/powstr.html)(link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where from you got the formula (1), s.t. this answer is only partial. It shows you what is the relation between the power $P$ radiated by the lamp in e.m. form, and the electric field amplitude $E_0$.

By the [Poynting theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector),

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot\vec {\mathcal S} = - \vec J\cdot\vec E \tag{i}$$

where $u$ is the density of e.m. energy, $\vec {\mathcal S}$ is the Poynting flux-vector meaning energy flowing per unit time and per unit surface. Since the e.m. energy inside the volume doesn't change, as the lamp irradiates all the time, the 1st term on the LHS is zero, and the RHS can be replaced by the power $P$ irradiated by the source in e.m. form. It is convenient to integrate over the volume around the lamp, which seems that you consider cylindrical, and apply the divergence law

$$\oint \vec {\mathcal S} \cdot d\vec S = P. \tag{i}$$

Since $\vec {\mathcal S}$ is equal over any such surface and $\vec {\mathcal S} || \vec S$,

$$P = {\mathcal S} \cdot S. \tag{ii}$$

The Poynting vector has the formula

$$\vec {\mathcal S}= \frac {1}{2}\vec E \times \vec H. \tag{iii}$$

In air, as in vacuum, $\vec E$ and $\vec H$ are mutually perpendicular, and

$$B_0 = E_0/c, \tag{iv}$$

s.t. using the known relation $\varepsilon_0 \mu_0 = 1/c^2$,

$$P = \frac {\varepsilon_0 c S}{2} E_0^2. \tag{v}$$

Another possible derivation of the intensity is to calculate the energy crossing a unit surface in unit time, which is equal to $u \cdot c$, then multiplying by the surface. Having in view that $u = \varepsilon_0 E_0^2/2,$ you obtain the same formula $\text {(v)}$.

What are the quantities $\rho$ and $V$, and why also appears $\omega^2$, *remains for you to clarify*.

Comment: Why do you say OP considers the volume cylindrical when its area is stated to be $4\pi r^2$?

Comment: Also in your equation (v) did you mean for $S$ to be a normalized vector? The difference between the two forms of S you use is not easy to see (at least in my browser) or does it mean "the surface" (often denoted with area $A$)

Comment: do you mean energy density $u=\frac12\epsilon_0E_0^2$ can be used ?

Comment: @Sofia The energy density does change, but the time average over a period does not change. The Poynting vector in eq (iii) does not have a one half.  Eq (v) is the first time you relate power to an amplitude instead of an instantaneous magnitude. The electric and magnetic fields are not always orthogonal, even in vacuum, so you can't cite that as the reason they are in this example. Finally, saying that the energy density is $\epsilon_0E_0^2/2$ is again only true for a time average and it very misleadingly hides that fact by cancelling out the (numerically equal) magnetic energy.